# Adicionar o texto do UITextField em um array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Opa, sei que pode parecer simples, mas estou com problemas ao pegar o texto digitado na UITextField e ao pressionar o botao incluir em um array, porem não estou conseguindo. Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
 var listaDeNomes: [String]?
 @IBOutlet weak var inserirNomesTF: UITextField!
 @IBAction func IncludePlayer(_ sender: Any) {
    if inserirNomesTF.text == ""{
        print("pelo menos 5 caracteres")
    }else {
       listaDeNomes.append(inserirNomesTF.text)
    }
  }
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem dois problemas:

1. O array não esta instanciado, não estando instanciado não lhe podes adicionar nada;
2. Não estas a lidar correctamente com opcionais.

Tenta algo deste género:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var listaDeNomes: [String]? = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inserirNomesTF: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func IncludePlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if inserirNomesTF.text!.count < 5{
            
            print("pelo menos 5 caracteres")
            
        }else {

            listaDeNomes!.append(inserirNomesTF.text!)
            
        }
      }
    }
```